# trying to locate the correct file to edit my internal linking anchor tags

Tags: hooks, links, wp-filesystem

I am trying to locate the correct file to edit my internal linking anchor tags i.e.`<a href=`

Can anyone point me to to the correct file? When I view the source code I see about 50 of them but I am not able to locate them in any files for editing????

I have looked in Header, Footer, Functions and many other hooks but could not locate the anchor tags???

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about what you mean by "internal linking anchor tags".

If it's something like your main logo internal homepage link, it might be hard coded into your header.php file, but if it's a link inside of post content, you would find it in the post editor. So depending on what and where it is, the links could be displayed in a number of different ways.

Update: You can edit your WordPress sites navigation menu's from the Dashboard >> Appearance >> [Menu's screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen).

Choose the applicable menu from the dropdown select in the "Edit Menus" tab, then you can easily edit existing links, or add more links to your menu. Once saved the changes to your menu will be reflected on your website.

Comment: I am talking about the menu links from my home page to other pages and back to my home page from the menu links.

Comment: Please see update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean menu links then just do it via Wordpress admin by going to Appearance > Menus. Depending how your theme is setup, the menu options available to you and those that you can create will be different.